# ModelForm "instance" parameter and foreign key field

Tags: python, django, modelform

I'm trying to initialize an object with in "instance" parameter but it doesn't go into the form. It is a required one so is_valid fails. Can someone please advise, I'm almost sure it's an easy mistake but can't spot it.

FORM:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

from tagging.forms import TagField

class BusinessEditForm(ModelForm):
tags = TagField()

class Meta:
    model = Business
    exclude = ('owner', 'pub_date')
```

Logic in views.py

```
if businessid:
    b = Business.objects.get(id=businessid)
    category = b.category
    assert(b.owner == request.user) or request.user.is_staff
    #form = forms.BusinessEditForm(request.POST, instance=b)
else:
    assert category.is_public or request.user.is_staff
    b = Business(owner=request.user, category_id=category.id)
    # form = forms.BusinessEditForm(request.POST, instance=b)
    isNew = True

if request.method == "POST":
    form = forms.BusinessEditForm(request.POST, instance=b)

    if form.is_valid():
```

This last line validates to False.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks,
Igor

Comment: It would help if you put the `BusinessEditForm` class (Does it inherit from ModelForm?).

Comment: thanks, updated in the original message, but basically the answer is yes )

Answer (score 0):

If  you need to pass `instance` to the form as if it was part of the form data, maybe you can try something like this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form_data = request.POST.copy()
    form_data['instance'] = b
    form = forms.BusinessEditForm(form_data)
```

Comment: used   form_data = request.POST.copy()
  if "category" not in form_data or not(form_data["category"]):
   form_data["category"] = category.id

And it works - thanks for that :) But I think the proper way is for 'instance' to do its job..

Answer (score 0):

If you're excluding required fields in the form, you'll need to set them programatically before calling `is_valid()` because the form wouldn't create a valid `Business` object otherwise. This is why `is_valid()` is returning `False`.

Comment: this is clear, but I was assuming 'instance' should be doing that

Comment: It only does so if the instance you returned actually has those fields set. I'm assuming it doesn't or else this wouldn't be returning an error.

Answer (score 0):

Without cluttering your views you could write into your forms clean method:

```
def clean(self):
  self.cleaned_data.update(excluded_field=self.instance.excluded_field)
  return super(YourForm, self).clean()
```

But you then should also require in your forms __init__ method, that the instance is given and has your excluded fields set.